# Simplifying code using the new andRelatedTo param

Tags: relations, plugin-sprig

I have the following code that works with Sprig. But with the new andRelatedTo param, I am wondering if this could be simplified? However, I am a little unsure if/where to start on this and how the new `andRelatedTo` would replace existing code.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

```
{% set defaultLimit = 35 %}
{% set search = search ?? '' %}
{% set sort = sort ?? 'title ASC' %}
{% set limit = limit ?? craft.app.request.queryParam('limit') ?? defaultLimit %}
{% set page = page ?? 1 %}
{% set category = craft.categories.id(_categoryId).one() %}

{# {% set alllowedEntryTypeHandles = ['sponsored', 'free'] %} #}
{% set limitOptions = [2, 5, 10, 25, 35, 50, 100, 'All'] %}
{% set limit = limit in limitOptions ? limit : defaultLimit %}

{% set params = {
  limit:limit,
  page: page,
} %}

{% set relatedParams = ['and'] %}
{% set relatedParams = relatedParams|merge([]) %}
{% set filterIds = '' %}

{% set pcdQueryString = null %}
{% set cbQueryString = null %}
{% set finishQueryString = null %}

{% if craft.app.request.queryParam('pcd') %}
  {% set pcdQueryString = craft.app.request.queryParam('pcd') | join(',') %}
  {% set filterIds = filterIds ~ ',' ~ pcdQueryString|join(',') %}
  {% set relatedParams = relatedParams|merge([pcdQueryString]) %}
  {% set params = params|merge({pcd:pcdQueryString}) %}
{% endif %}

{% if craft.app.request.queryParam('cb') %}
  {% set cbQueryString = craft.app.request.queryParam('cb') | join(',') %}
  {% set filterIds = filterIds ~ ',' ~ cbQueryString|join(',') %}
  {% set relatedParams = relatedParams|merge([cbQueryString]) %}
  {% set params = params|merge({cb:cbQueryString}) %}
{% endif %}

{% if craft.app.request.queryParam('finish') %}
  {% set finishQueryString = craft.app.request.queryParam('finish') | join(',') %}
  {% set filterIds = filterIds ~ ',' ~ finishQueryString|join(',') %}
  {% set relatedParams = relatedParams|merge([finishQueryString]) %}
  {% set params = params|merge({finish:finishQueryString}) %}
{% endif %}

{# SAERCH #}
{% if craft.app.request.queryParam('search') %}
  {% set params = params|merge({search:search}) %}
{% endif %}

 {% set filterTags = craft.entries
   .id(filterIds)
   .orderBy('title ASC')
   .all() %}

{% set allProductsQuery = craft.products
  .relatedTo(category)
  .all() %}

 {% set productsQuery = craft.products
   .search(search)
   .with( [
     'department',
     'productImage',
     'finish',
     'pcd',
     'variants',
     'thread',
     'seat',
     'hexHead'
   ])
   .orderBy(sort)
   .limit(limit)
   .relatedTo(relatedParams) %}

{% do sprig.pushUrl('?' ~ params|url_encode) %}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a lot of code to post in a question!

The basic gist is that instead of merging new related params with `relatedParams|merge` and *then* applying to the query, you can call `andRelatedTo(newParams)` directly on the query.

```
{% set productsQuery = craft.products %}
{% set someEntryId = craft.app.request.queryParam('someEntryId') %}

{# BEFORE #}
{% if someEntryId %}
    {% set relatedParams = relatedParams|merge([someEntryId]) %}
{% endif %}
{% set productsQuery = productsQuery.relatedTo(relatedParams) %}

{# AFTER #}
{% if someEntryId %}
    {% do productsQuery.andRelatedTo(someEntryId) %}
{% endif %}
```

I explain this in more detail in the [Sprig Filters](https://putyourlightson.com/sprig/videos#sprig-filters) video series.

Comment: Can you mark this as the correct answer, assuming you are satisfied with it, so that this question appears resolved?